# DirectX and Cuda performance

Tags: directx

I started Cuda recently and studied samples. I found somewhat strange.

At 'fluidsD3D9' sample DirectX present funtction takes 15~20 milisec.
I Checked Time like source code below.

```
LARGE_INTEGER start, end, f;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&f);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
hr = g_pD3DDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

float finterval = (float)(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / 
                  (float)(f.QuadPart / 1000);

printf("\nPresent : %f\n", finterval);
```

But SwapBuffer does not takes time at 'fluidsGL' sample.
It seems that block occur at 'fluidsD3D9' sample.
FPS also differ DirectX and OpenGL Sample because of this time.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should read this MSDN article as to why your timing approach doesn't work: [Accurately Profiling Direct3D API Calls (Direct3D 9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172234.aspx). In short, you can't easily predict when the GPU work is actually getting kicked off as Direct3D batches heavily to try to avoid the kernel-transition overhead, and the GPU is usually not in sync with the CPU.

> As someone else noted, Direct3D 9 is ancient and does not really support GPGPU. For a more apples-to-apples comparison, try the DirectX 11 DirectCompute sample [FluidCS11](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/FluidCS11).

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a problem. It is more a driver design and optimization difference. All the D3D calls don't do much and when you call Present, you end up flushing most of a frame that was queued before. Sure you may have done something that make present bigger than it should, but it is a black box and even with nvidia support, it is often difficult to get ride of it.

On a side note, d3d9 is pretty old, and the driver may be less good than it used to be with modern OS, any d3d development now should use d3d11 ( and the 1% using d3d12 ).